# Project from a double nested array by checking a value inside the array Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
{
    _id: 'uniquewId',
    programs: [
        {
            prgName: 'prgOne',
            progress: '5',
            addedBy: 'coach'
            exercises: [
                {
                     date: '1/12/20',
                     exercises: [
                         {
                              exId: 'pushup',
                              progress: 5,
                              attributes: [
                                  {
                                     id: 'myId',
                                     done: true
                                  },
                                  {
                                     id: 'myId2',
                                     done: false
                                  } 
                              ]
                         },
                         {
                              exId: 'situp',
                              progress: 5,
                              attributes: [
                                  {
                                     id: 'myId',
                                     done: true
                                  },
                                  {
                                     id: 'myId2',
                                     done: true
                                  } 
                              ]
                         }
                     ] 
                },
                {
                    date: '2/12/20',
                    exercises: [
                         {
                              exId: 'pushup',
                              progress: 5,
                              attributes: [
                                  {
                                     id: 'myId',
                                     done: true
                                  },
                                  {
                                     id: 'myId2',
                                     done: false
                                  } 
                              ]
                         },
                         {
                              exId: 'situp',
                              progress: 5,
                              attributes: [
                                  {
                                     id: 'myId',
                                     done: fase
                                  },
                                  {
                                     id: 'myId2',
                                     done: false
                                  } 
                              ]
                         }
                     ] 
                }   
            ]
        },
        {
            prgName: 'prgTwo',
            progress: '5',
            addedBy: 'coach2'
            exercises: [
                 {
                     date: '1/12/20',
                     exercises: [
                         {
                              exId: 'pushup',
                              progress: 5,
                              attributes: [
                                  {
                                     id: 'myId',
                                     done: true
                                  },
                                  {
                                     id: 'myId2',
                                     done: true
                                  } 
                              ]
                         },
                         {
                              exId: 'situp',
                              progress: 5,
                              attributes: [
                                  {
                                     id: 'myId',
                                     done: false
                                  },
                                  {
                                     id: 'myId2',
                                     done: false
                                  } 
                              ]
                         }
                     ] 
                },
                {
                    date: '2/12/20',
                    exercises: [
                         {
                              exId: 'pushup',
                              progress: 5,
                              attributes: [
                                  {
                                     id: 'myId',
                                     done: true
                                  },
                                  {
                                     id: 'myId2',
                                     done: false
                                  } 
                              ]
                         },
                         {
                              exId: 'situp',
                              progress: 5,
                              attributes: [
                                  {
                                     id: 'myId',
                                     done: true
                                  },
                                  {
                                     id: 'myId2',
                                     done: false
                                  } 
                              ]
                         }
                     ] 
                }   
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

That above is the structure of my document. 
What i want to do is from the programs array i want to project the name of exercises that have atleat one document inside attribute array which has done key marked as true. What i am trying to do is figure out exercises which has done set to true inside the attributes array
Is there any way i can get the output like:

```
{
    _id: 'uniquewId',
    programs: [
        {
            prgName: 'prgOne',
            exercises: [
                'pushup',
                'situp'  
            ]  
        },
        {
            prgName: 'prgTwo',
            exercises: [
                'pushup',
                'situp'  
            ]  
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why only single element for `prgTwo`?

Comment: Sorry it shoud have two elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a **tedious process**.

With [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator we can iterate over arrays. Also `$map` allows transform array of objects into array of strings.

```
[{k1:v1}, {k2:v2}, ...] -> [v1, v2, ...]
```

---

## Pseudocode

*1st step*. We perform complex aggregation and pre-calculate values

```
for (Programs program: doc.programs) {
    return {
        prgName : program.prgName,
        exercises : [
            for (Exercises exer1: program.exercises) {
                for (Exercises exer2: exer1.exercises) {
                    return {
                        exId : exer2.exId,
                        done : exer2.attributes.done.contains(true)
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

*2nd step*. We construct desired result

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      programs: {
        $map: {
          input: "$programs",
          as: "program",
          in: {
            prgName: "$$program.prgName",
            exercises: {
              $reduce: {
                input: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$$program.exercises",
                    as: "exer1",
                    in: {
                      $map: {
                        input: "$$exer1.exercises",
                        as: "exer2",
                        in: {
                          exId: "$$exer2.exId",
                          done: {
                            $in: [
                              true,
                              "$$exer2.attributes.done"
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                initialValue: [],
                in: {
                  $concatArrays: [
                    "$$value",
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      programs: {
        $map: {
          input: "$programs",
          as: "program",
          in: {
            prgName: "$$program.prgName",
            exercises: {
              $reduce: {
                input: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$$program.exercises",
                    cond: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$this.done",
                        true
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                initialValue: [],
                in: {
                  $concatArrays: [
                    "$$value",
                    {
                      $cond: [
                        {
                          $in: [
                            "$$this.exId",
                            "$$value"
                          ]
                        },
                        [],
                        [
                          "$$this.exId"
                        ]
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bc2-Qd-thWk)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but there was a mistake in my question. I have updated the question. Sorry :)

Comment: Thanks it works :) . Is there any way it can be done using a single projection. Just asking out of curiosity

Comment: @AkhilS Sure, but it will be a big monster :)